# PromQL simple aggregation

Tags: promql

I have a very simple example yet I can't find how to implement it in promQL.

I have 2 metrics, first one is let's say my_metric1 which returns 100 timeseries grouped in 3 categories (category="A", category="B", and category="C"). I would like to keep only category "A" and "B" so the easiest way to do this is my_metric1{category=~"A|B"} which works fine.

Now I would like to generalise this. Let's say I have a second metric my_metric2 which returns 50 timeseries but they all belong to either category "A" or "B". I would like to take the "A|B" directly from here without coding it.

My first guess (which doesn't work) is : my_metric1 * on (category) group_left(category) (my_metric2).

I tried many variants and they either give me a syntax error or a "many-to-many matching not allowed".

Any ideas?

Comment: Found it!
my_metric1 * on(category) group_left sum(my_metric2) by (category)

Comment: The last command is not working properly! The sum(my_metric2) multiplies my_metric1 by some numbers. I'm looking for a solution to either replace that sum or transform to boolean.

Comment: This works:
sum by(category) (my_metric2) > bool 0
but the problem is if I combine it with the group_left, the > bool 0 will be applied to the whole resulting vector. Adding parenthesis raises an error...